# nodejs sequelize connect to a remote mySQL database always give ETIMEDOUT

Tags: mysql, node.js, xampp, sequelize.js

i need your help regarding connecting sequelize to a remote mySQL database

sequelize connects fine when i set host attribute to 'localhost' like this:

```
new Sequelize('billsmanager', 'root', '12345', {
        host: `localhost`,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        },
        pool: {
            max: 25,
            min: 0,
            idle: 10000
        },
    })
```

then i've tried to put my local IP address at home instead of 'localhost' and ETIMEDOUT comes

i tried freeinfinity hosting site it gives ETIMEDOUT

my office server it gives ETIMEDOUT

even i tried my brother's home server and it gives me ETIMEDOUT

and even my network at home it gives ETIMEDOUT

someone suggested here to add inbound rule in firewall for port 3306 and it doesn't work

and commenting bind-address in my.ini didn't work too

i'm using XAMPP

i don't know really why this happens

can you help me?

thanks so much in advance,i really need this to work

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a `mysql` database that exists locally on the same machine as your `node` app - or are you trying to connect to a db that is publicly available such as an AWS RDS instance? If you are trying to connect to a remote host, please include details about the provider. If it is AWS for example you will need to configure the security group properly.

Comment: I was trying to connect nodejs to a database in hostinger and I get the error then I said why I don't try to connect locally by my ip address so I tried that and it gives the same error,I suspect it has something to do with the network cz when I connect via localhost it connects but when I pit 192.168.1.2 (my laptop local ip address) it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

i've solved it at last with very silly solution

i added a connect timeout to 100Sec and it worked and connected after like 12Sec

i wrote the initialization like this:

```
sequelizer: new Sequelize('billsmanager', 'root', '12345', {
        host: `192.168.1.2`,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        dialectOptions: {
            connectTimeout:100000
        },
        define: {
            timestamps: false
        },
        pool: {
            max: 25,
            min: 0,
            idle: 10000
        },
    }),
```

thanks